# Loaded image from file not always showing up in ImageView

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

My `ImageView` which I load from a `File` is contained in a `PopupWindow` in a `Fragment`. The image doesn't always show up. It seems random.

The image is supposed to be from a taken picture. I know the file is written correctly, because when I go to the next activity and load another ImageView from the same file, it shows up no problem.

Please note that this `Fragment` also has another `ImageView`, but not in a `PopupWindow` and that one always shows after I take the picture. I suspect it has to do something with being in a `PopupWindow`.

*Why is it only loading the ImageView randomly?*

**ImageView loaded from File in PopupWindow**

```
File file = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), step.getExtraImageFilename());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            Bitmap imgFromFile = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            extraImage.setImageBitmap(imgFromFile);
            extraImage.invalidate();
            fis.close();
```

**Start Camera & OnActivityResult**

```
private void startCameraActivity(int requestCode) {
    ImageHandler imageHandler = new ImageHandler(getActivity());
    String filename = "";

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_PICTURE:
        filename = imageHandler.getImageFilename(step.getChecklistId(), step.getOrder(), false);
        step.setImageFilename(filename);
        break;
    case REQUEST_PICTURE_EXTRA:
        filename = imageHandler.getImageFilename(step.getChecklistId(), step.getOrder(), true);
        step.setExtraImageFilename(filename);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    File file = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
            Log.i("IMAGE FILE WRITTEN", step.getImageFilename());
            ImageHandler.compressAndRotateImage(getActivity(), step.getImageFilename());

            finishStep();
            showResult();
            checkIfAllFinished();
            if (step.getIsAllFinished()) { ((StepActivity)getActivity()).goToNextStep(); }
        }
        break;

    case REQUEST_PICTURE_EXTRA:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i("IMAGE FILE WRITTEN", step.getExtraImageFilename());
            ImageHandler.compressAndRotateImage(getActivity(), step.getExtraImageFilename());

            if (step.getReqPicture()) { step.setIsReqPictureFinished(true); }
            showExtraPicture();
            checkIfAllFinished();
            if (step.getIsAllFinished()) { ((StepActivity)getActivity()).goToNextStep(); }
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

**Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: could you post your permissions in mainfest file ?

Comment: @mohammedmomn added permissions in OP.